# How to display multiple object values in alert box using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, alert

```
function myFunction()
{
    alert(document.getElementById("myname").value+','+document.getElementById("myphone")+','+document.getElementById("mycountry")+','+document.getElementById("myemail"));
   
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more details?

Comment: get user input from html through input tag and i need to display those values in pop up alert box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems pretty straightforward to me

I just refactor a bit your function

```js
function myFunction() {
  const message = ['myname', 'myphone', 'mycountry', 'myemail']
    .map(id => document.getElementById(id).value)
    .join(',')
  alert(message);

}
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="myname" placeholder="myname" />
  <input id="myphone" placeholder="myphone" />
  <input id="mycountry" placeholder="mycountry" />
  <input id="myemail" placeholder="myemail" />
</div>
<div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Show alert</button>
</div>
```